# Django REST framework dict to viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like use viewsets with router. I have script with dict response.

I can work with APIView because result is dict response, but viewsets need serializer and queryset. How I can do with viewsets?

```
class Myapi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        vars_dict = my_script_result_dict
        response = JsonResponse(vars_dict)
        return response
```

i would like use browse api

Answer (score 0):

to render a manual response you can do this

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class Myapi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        vars_dict = my_script_result_dict
        response = JsonResponse(vars_dict)
        return Response({'responce': response}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you response, i have try but is not work with router `router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'inventory', views.Myapi)` i have the same error assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and could

Comment: if i remove the router , is work correctly with UI , they are not solution for this work with router ?